# Replacing old Nutone Despard/triple Switch with Triple Rocker

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I'm looking to replace an old Nutone Despard/triple switch, which has individual controls for the light, vent & heat aspects of the overhead unit.  Through a series of push-in and jumper wires, each toggle works independently.  I can share that there are two separate hot wires feeding the top/bottom switches which seem to be relayed/jumpered to the middle switch.

The new triple rocker has a single terminal for the line in, with 3 terminals for the 3 loads (light, fan and heat).  My sense is I could pigtail the two hot wires to the line in, but then it's not obvious how the 2 remaining wires could feed 3 separate loads...

Hopefully my image brings some clarity and thank you for your guidance!!

[image: Note the electrical tape I used to mark the two hot wires]

[image: Current Switch]

[image: Triple rocker I'd like to use]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your old setup had two separate hots. The new switch (same type of switch as I have in two bathrooms) is designed for a single hot, i.e., a single *circuit*. There are two issues to consider:

- Available Power

This should not be an issue. The heat uses a lot, possibly as much as 12A, but the fan and light hardly anything. If one of these circuits is a 20A circuit then you are almost certainly fine using that circuit. If they are both 15A then it could be marginal, depending on the actual power usage of each of the 3 devices.

- Neutral

With two separate hots, you should also have two separate neutrals. Using just one hot, you will need to make sure that all 3 devices use the same neutral, or that their neutrals are all tied together at some point to the neutral that matches the hot wire.

---

The next step is to figure out which wires are which. You may have two existing circuits, you may have one with ongoing to another location - though I doubt that and it would not be advisable except possibly for some additional lights, as the heat uses most of a 15A or 20A circuit capacity.

Black wires are normally hot (line) and switched hot (load) but not neutral. White wires are normally neutral but not hot or switched hot. *However*, a white wire can be hot or (if done improperly) switched hot, which indicates a an old-style *switch loop*. That is the only logical explanation for the middle switch having a white wire. With a switch loop, instead of panel -> switch -> device, it is panel ->device -> switch. Which means a bit of rearranging of wires here, probably including some rewiring at the "vent", will be needed.

With a triple switch using a common hot (i.e., your new desired switch), you can't use switch loops. It has to be hot (common) and neutral (common) to the switch box, then neutral to all 3 devices and 3 separate switched hot wires to the 3 devices. Thinking about this a little more, there may be a complication here. Key question:

**Are there 3 or 4 cables in the box?**

If there are 4 cables then it is one for each device (probably regular to heat, regular to light, switch loop to vent) plus one bringing hot & neutral for 1 or 2 of the devices.

If there are 3 cables (which I *think* is the case) then the hot from the switch loop is feeding hot to the others...and then this gets really messy.

So a little more detail about the cables and also determining which wire(s) are actually hot is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!  I do have two neutrals pigtailed together in the back of the box (noticing they have a faint, red line *added photo*)  The two pigtailed neutral wires each come in with a black hot wire (marked with electrical tape) BUT the used white neutral wire is bundled with a black wire that isn't hot...Could I use one of the hot wires and then pigtail the accompanying neutral wire to the three terminals?  Could I dictate the order of the switches (e.g. light, fan and heat from top to bottom)?

Comment: Switches can be any sequence you want - my electrician voted (and won...) for least to most power/effect, so bottom light, middle fan, top heat. But up to you. More important is figuring out the wiring. I'll add some more to my answer.

Comment: I added a photo with labels.  You're correct; it is 3 cables.

Comment: The plot thickens. Logically the jumper between the top switches should be hot because otherwise one switch would be dependent on the other - something ain't right. Also, is the white wire hot when all switches are off?

Comment: I just turned on the breaker and every single wire (including the white) is hot when all switches are off.  Anecdotally, when I was really "winging it", and plugged in the 3 rocker the way I assumed it would work, I was able to get the heat and light to work IF the fan was also switched on, otherwise neither would operate independently.

Comment: That may be induced/phantom voltage. Turn the breaker off. Disconnect every wire that is coming from a cable - except the neutral bundle and you can leave the jumper between the switches in place. Tag each wire somehow so that you know how to put them back where they came from. Then turn on the breaker and check each wire. If more than one shows as hot with a non-contact tester then check the bare end of each wire with the bare copper ground using a multimeter - that should tell you the true "hot" wires, which will be helpful in sorting this out. Then turn off the breaker.

Comment: OK, the one marked as "hot", next to "heat" (this would be bottom of switch if it was in wall) is NOT hot.  The only hot wire is the one closer to the "Light" (this would be top of switch in wall).

Comment: Starting to figure this out: Please confirm that: Hot wire comes in to "light" switch, not hot goes out ("thick" black wire) plus jumper goes to fan. not hot ("thick" white wire) goes out from fan, *which is in the same cable as the not hot wire from the light; jumper from fan goes to heat, thin black wire goes out from heat paired with one of the neutrals. **Right?**

Comment: exactly!  I also edited the above image.  Can I use this, now?  The White neutral wire to Fan being a load? 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaDof.png

Comment: "White neutral being a load" is a common but totally incorrect statement. "Neutral is white", but "white is not neutral". As in, the correct question is "Can I use white as load?" (Sorry if that seems really nitpicky, but it gets to the core of serious confusion about US wiring.)

Comment: If you weren't "nitpicky" (you're not), I wouldn't learn :)

Comment: But back to the real problem: You have 3 cables - black hot/white neutral from panel *good*. Black switched hot/white neutral to heat *good*. Black switched hot to light and white switched hot to vent *not good*. And presumably up in the ceiling the neutral for the heat is shared with the light and vent. The problem is that this means that the current flow in the light/vent cable is not balanced because it has switched hot but doesn't have neutral.

Comment: Is it *super bad*? No. Super bad would be if the heat (which uses several times the current of the vent and light) were the one going up without its neutral. But it isn't to code (including old code - i.e., this is not a recent change to code0 and since you are making changes you need to fix it. Which isn't easy. The usual methods of handling this are either 4 cables (1 in, 3 out) or 3 cables *with one of those having an extra (red) wire*. But you can't pull cables out of thin air. You only need 4 wires going from the switch to the ceiling - but they need to be all in one cable.

Comment: Most likely originally there was one device (light) and then it was changed to 3 but they didn't run the correct cable. Or I suspect more likely there were originally two devices and they added a 3rd without adding another cable. Because adding another cable is the hard part. (I had my electrician do that for me - not sure if he would even attempt it today as he has gotten older and my attic has gotten nastier...)

Comment: This is going to sound silly this deep into the conversation, but I'm also OK forgoing Heat altogether (it's literally never used).

Comment: From a pure replacement standpoint, now that we've confirmed the wiring scheme, you would connect that incoming hot to the "common" on the new switch, and the 3 identified switched hots (two black, one white) to the 3 switched terminals. And you would not use the two jumper wires. But that would not be valid according to code due to the neutral imbalance.

Comment: Not silly at all. Without heat, this works fine with a little rearrangement of wires here and in the ceiling.

Comment: SUCCESS!  Thank you so much for your guidance (learned things I can apply outside of this individual switch).  I really appreciate it.  

How do we mark this as closed :)?

Comment: Near the top of the answer there should be a place you can make a checkmark "accepted".